# Troubles with ruby-2.X installation using RVM

Tags: ruby, rvm

I recently came across of the ruby-2.0.0-p0 installation. After the successfully installation of the rvm i type the following command at the bash.

```
rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p0
```

This this the result log.

```bash
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: debian/wheezy_sid/i386/ruby-2.0.0-p0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing Ruby from source to: /home/javier/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #downloading ruby-2.0.0-p0, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #extracting ruby-2.0.0-p0 to /home/javier/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #extracted to /home/javier/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p0
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #configuring
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #compiling
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #installing
Removing old Rubygems files...
Installing rubygems-2.0.0 for ruby-2.0.0-p0 ...
Error running 'env GEM_PATH=/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0:/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global:/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0:/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global GEM_HOME=/home/javier/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0 /home/javier/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby /home/javier/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/setup.rb', please read /home/javier/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/rubygems.install.log
Installation of rubygems did not complete successfully.
Saving wrappers to '/home/javier/.rvm/bin'.
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #adjusting #shebangs for (gem irb erb ri rdoc testrb rake).
ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #importing default gemsets, this may take time ...
Install of ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #complete
Making gemset ruby-2.0.0-p0 pristine.
Error running '' under ,
please read /home/javier/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gemset.pristine.log
Making gemset ruby-2.0.0-p0@global pristine.
Error running '' under ,
please read /home/javier/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gemset.pristine.log
```

Note that the process goes without troubles until the installation of ruby gems.
What's going on here ??

Any help appreciated.

**First comment output**

```bash
cat /home/javier/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/rubygems.install.log
```

```bash
/home/javier/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file -- openssl (LoadError)
from /home/javier/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /home/javier/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/security.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/javier/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /home/javier/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /home/javier/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/package.rb:43:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/javier/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /home/javier/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /home/javier/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/installer.rb:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/javier/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /home/javier/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /home/javier/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/request_set.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/javier/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems.rb:195:in `finish_resolve'
from /home/javier/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/rdoc.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/javier/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /home/javier/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /home/javier/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/uninstaller.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/javier/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /home/javier/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
from /home/javier/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/commands/setup_command.rb:440:in `uninstall_old_gemcutter'
from /home/javier/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/commands/setup_command.rb:144:in `execute'
from /home/javier/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/command.rb:305:in `invoke_with_build_args'
from /home/javier/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/command_manager.rb:170:in `process_args'
from /home/javier/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/command_manager.rb:130:in `run'
from /home/javier/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:60:in `run'
from setup.rb:45:in `<main>'
RubyGems 2.0.0 installed
```

**Second comment output And the other command**

```bash
rvm use --default 2.0.0
```

```
RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.

You need to change your terminal emulator preferences to allow login shell.
Sometimes it is required to use `/bin/bash --login` as the command.
Please visit https://rvm.io/integration/gnome-terminal/ for a example.
```

Comment: Run `cat /home/javier/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/rubygems.install.log` what's the output of that?

Comment: What do you want to do? `Install of ruby-2.0.0-p0 - #complete` - doesn't that imply that ruby was installed successfully? 

Do this: `rvm use --default 2.0.0`, and then `ruby -v`. What are you getting? and also output the log file like Leo said.

Comment: Type `rvm requirements` and make sure you've installed all the necessary requirements.

Comment: I edit the entry to add the @LeoCorrea and ForbiddenOverseer requests. I will try with the rvm requirements. My rvm version is 1.8.15

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try the following

```
$ rvm remove 2.0.0 # get rid of unsuccessful installation
$ rvm get head --autolibs=3 # get the latest RVM and build required libs
$ rvm requirements # just in case, install all other required stuff
$ rvm install ruby-2.0.0
```

If at any of those commands fails at any point. Update your question with the logs.

Comment: Very useful, the trouble was the rvm requirements.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm it was the requirements for me as well. Had to install Xcode after running it once and receiving an error.

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact same problem. The solution was elegant and simple.

Just **update your gems direct from the command line**:

```
sudo gem update --system
```

That's it!
Terminal will now show:

```
Updating RubyGems
Updating rubygems-update
Successfully installed rubygems-update-2.0.3
Updating RubyGems to 2.0.3
Installing RubyGems 2.0.3
RubyGems 2.0.3 installed
```

Comment: I used this command line, ruby update to 2.0.3 but I don't know where did Ruby install? What directory? I need absolute path to config with apache2

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact same problem, same error message, etc. I don't know about you, but I use MacPorts, and through that I have libraries like OpenSSL installed, which I think may have contributed to my trouble.

I just got it working on my system; I'm not sure exactly what I did right but here are the steps I took:

1. Set up my `~/.rvmrc` to match the first code block [here](https://rvm.io/integration/macports/).
2. Uninstalled 2.0.0 through rvm (`rvm remove 2.0.0`).
3. Removed the folders for ruby-2.0.0, rubygems-2.0.0 and the dependency packages like OpenSSL and YAML in `~/.rvm/src`.
4. Executed `rvm install 2.0.0 --with-opt-dir=/opt/local --autolibs=0`. `/opt/local` is my MacPorts prefix directory, and `autolibs=0` disables any dependency installation so it didn't have the opportunity to use something other than my MacPorts libraries. If you get through this step without red console output you're past the errors you were having above.
5. Not knowing if having an empty default gemset was the problem I also ran `rvm use --create 2.0.0@...` to get a non-default gemset created and then (successfully) installed a gem and its dependencies into it.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Open Up the Terminal and then Go to **Edit > Profile Preferences** and then go to the Tab "**Title and Command**" and Check "**Run Command as Login Shell**".

Boot Up a Bash and Now you can install Gems directly from the terminal without the use of sudo and the error "**RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.**" will be eliminated.

Cheers.