# Can't install rubygems with ruby 2.0.0

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems, zlib

I've been trying to install rubygems for hours, but it keeps failing. The error is:

```
Installing rubygems-2.0.3 for ruby-2.0.0-p0..............................................................................................................................
Error running 'env GEM_PATH=/Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0:/Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global:/Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0:/Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@global 
GEM_HOME=/Users/Chris/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0 /Users/Chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby -d /Users/Chris/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.3/setup.rb --verbose',
please read /Users/Chris/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/rubygems.install.log
```

(Sorry if that's difficult to read, I'm not exactly sure how to break it up.)

rubygems.install.log:

Top few lines:

```
[2013-03-21 06:55:13] /Users/Chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/ruby
Exception `LoadError' at /Users/Chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:1073 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/operating_system
Exception `LoadError' at /Users/Chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems.rb:1082 - cannot load such file -- rubygems/defaults/ruby
mkdir -p /Users/Chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0
mkdir -p /Users/Chris/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin
```

Full file: [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/NUnLyTVF)

I've tried reinstalling Xcode, made sure I've install xcode command line tools, Rvm, ruby 2.0.0, pretty much everything. I've also tried removing all the other ruby versions and rvm requirements doesn't tell me I need anything I don't have.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

EDIT: Also, I just managed to reinstall 1.9.3, with rubygems 1.9.3, absolutely fine.

EDIT2: Okay, now I'm getting the error:

```
/Users/Chris/.rvm/src/rubygems-2.0.0/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file -- zlib (LoadError)
```

in the log.

Edit 3: Ran rvm requirements, nothing I didn't have already. Trying to install zlib gives me errors with configure and make.

Configure:

```
unknown option: --disable-shared
```

Make:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
```

Trying to configure and make manually (without the disable shared flag) removes the configure issue but leaves the make issue.

Edit 4:

So after a trying several different things, it suddenly worked. I decided to try rvm one last time, and everything worked fine. I'd post what I did, but I really have no idea.

Comment: Did you tried gem update --system to install the latest rubygems-update?

Comment: Yes. Response: 

ERROR:  Loading command: update (LoadError)
 cannot load such file -- zlib

ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass

Comment: run rvm requirements if you are missing something I think you are missing zlib pkg you can install it by rvm pkg install zlib and then you need to reinstall ruby

Comment: Tried that, got errors trying to install zlib, details in main post.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing some libraries while installing ruby type

```
rvm requirements
```

and see which libraries you are missing and install the same, in particular install the zlib pkg and also you need to re install ruby

```
rvm pkg install zlib
rvm reinstall ruby
```

I am using ubuntu so I can install the libraries like this

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
rvm reinstall ruby
```

Comment: Tried that, got errors trying to install zlib, details in main post.

Comment: I tried doing this and Leo Correa's solution. Then I got another error which was solved here but that solution didn't work out for me either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15129355/ruby-2-0-rails-gem-install-error-cannot-load-such-file-openssl

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this question [Troubles with ruby-2.X installation using RVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15232076/troubles-with-ruby-2-0-0-p0-installation-using-rvm/15233923#15233923)

pretty much

```
$ rvm remove 2.0.0 # get rid of unsuccessful installation
$ rvm get head --autolibs=3 # get the latest RVM and build required libs
$ rvm requirements # just in case, install all other required stuff
$ rvm install ruby-2.0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried

```
$ rvm remove 2.0.0 # get rid of unsuccessful installation
$ rvm get head --autolibs=3 # get the latest RVM and build required libs
$ rvm requirements # just in case, install all other required stuff
$ rvm install ruby-2.0.0
```

But it didn't work. Ruby 2.0.0 seems to be installed successfully.

I open a new terminal, then

```
rvm use 2.0.0
rvm rubygems latest
```

It works. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This is expected output when you run with ruby -d. There's nothing wrong with it.